# can't get tomcat to offer TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_... ciphers

Tags: linux, tomcat, java, tls

my tomcat (7.0.52) Connector is configured with a cipher list like 
    ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
    TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA"

all those are supported by openjdk1.7 installed on the server (verified).

the keystore is initialized with keytool, using

```
    keytool -genkey -alias Tomcat -keyalg RSA -sigalg SHA256withRSA -keysize 2048 ...
```

In ssl handshake debug output, I can see the client offers these ciphers, but server picks TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA only, which is not the strongest:

```
ClientHello, TLSv1.2Jul 04, 2014 2:38:31 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,...
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Unsupported extension type_35, data:
Unsupported extension type_13172, data:
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA256withRSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA1withECDSA, Unknown (hash:0x4, signature:0x2), SHA1withDSA
***
Jul 04, 2014 2:38:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
%% Initialized:  [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
matching alias: tomcat
% Negotiating:  [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
```

If I remove TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA from tomcat's cipher list, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA is used. If i remove both TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_xxx, then I get a handshake failure (no ciphers in common).

I Can't figure out what's missing or bad in the configuration.

Any input much appreciated...

Comment: Do you have an ECDSA signing key, or is the "-keyalg RSA" the only key in your store?

Comment: Thank's for this comment, I'll explore this way (I probably only have the RSA signing key)

Comment: I suspect it'll fail anyway for other reasons - I found your question while (inconclusively) searching for information on the state of ECDSA support in Tomcat. But if you do only have an RSA key, it'll be forced to use a TLS_..._RSA_... suite.

Answer (score 2):

Your ciphers should be listed in order of preference.

But you listed `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA` before `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA`.

Try reversing their order in the list.

You may also wish to reorder the entire list so that all the 256-bit ciphers appear before all the 128-bit ciphers.

You also need to have `SSLHonorCipherOrder="true"` set in your `<Connector>`.

Comment: No, order is not the issue, tomcat behaves the same if you set 256-b first. Moreover, I don't understand why the ECDHE_ECDSA_xxx are not used by either tomcat or JSSE (I could not determine which layer is "faulty").

Comment: Ah, you are missing some stuff from your `<Connector>` then. I made an edit. See also https://blog.eveoh.nl/2014/02/tls-ssl-ciphers-pfs-tomcat/

Comment: thanks for inputs, I saw the SSLHonorCipherOrder, but it is for APR enabled connectors. I currently use the BIO/NIO connector.

APR is indeed an option, I may consider later, only in case I cannot get this working with BIO/NIO.

Comment: You need it anyway, since you are not really secure against various SSL attacks without it.